# How to run code in wordpress to handle database

Tags: database, wordpress

Whenever I have to run code on the database, change posts, or terms or what have you, I am running it on a custom page template.

Since this has been working for me up to know, I didn’t think about it much. But I need to delete a ton of terms now from a custom taxonomy and I can’t do it on the test page very effectively. Meaning I get 504 gateway errors all the time, because the code takes too long to run, and deletes only a part of the terms.

So I am wondering, if I need to run custom code to change a lot of data, what is the most efficient method to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people use a plugin named [Code Snippets](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) for this. Otherwise it's often more efficient to use direct [SQL Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) using [phpMyAdmin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) for example.